# Parsing a web page with stringr

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have this project where I am trying to extract numbers from a web page. Below is an example of the text I am trying to parse.

> "\naAreas =
>   [\n[**107447478**,2490,1925,559,1016,962,0,18,0,1,110,],\n[**107447440**,2366,1800,565,1033,811,1,46,0,0,23,],\n[**107447521**,2933,2396,543,921,1566,0,11,0,0,115,]\n];\naRoutes
>   = [\n];\n$(function() {\n    $(\".typeTip\").attr(\"title\", \"T=Trad, S=Sport, TR=Toprope\");\n    showTips();\n});\n"

I am looking for the numbers in bold, so anything between "\n[" and ",". I am trying to do this with the stringr package in R, but I'm not really all that familiar with regular expressions and I'm striking out.

Comment: What about `\\n\[(\d+)`? I believe R supports lookbehinds so, assuming I'm correct, you can actually use `(?<=\\n\[)\d+(?=,)` [See this regex run on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KNTkPV/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
x <- "\naAreas = [\n[107447478,2490,1925,559,1016,962,0,18,0,1,110,],\n[107447440,2366,1800,565,1033,811,1,46,0,0,23,],\n[107447521,2933,2396,543,921,1566,0,11,0,0,115,]\n];\naRoutes = [\n];\n$(function() {\n $(\".typeTip\").attr(\"title\", \"T=Trad, S=Sport, TR=Toprope\");\n showTips();\n});\n"

stringr::str_extract_all(x, '(?<=\n\\[)\\d+')
## [[1]]
## [1] "107447478" "107447440" "107447521"
```

The`(?<=\n\\[)` is a lookbehind and says make sure a new line and square brace proceed but don't capture them.  The `\\d+` says grab as many digits as you can after until there are no more digits.

Answer (score 1):

`stringr` builds on `stringi`. This is a different approach using `stringi` and `V8` since you've got javascript there:

```
library(V8)
library(stringi)

js <- "\naAreas = [\n[107447478,2490,1925,559,1016,962,0,18,0,1,110,],\n[107447440,2366,1800,565,1033,811,1,46,0,0,23,],\n[107447521,2933,2396,543,921,1566,0,11,0,0,115,]\n];\naRoutes = [\n];\n$(function() {\n $(\".typeTip\").attr(\"title\", \"T=Trad, S=Sport, TR=Toprope\");\n showTips();\n});\n"

ctx <- v8()
```

We have to remove the jQuery bits since V8 can't deal with those, but once we do we can evaluate it as javascript:

```
ctx$eval(sprintf("var %s ", paste0(stri_split_lines(js)[[1]][2:6], collapse="\n")))
```

Then get the data:

```
ctx$get("aAreas")
##           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11]
## [1,] 107447478 2490 1925  559 1016  962    0   18    0     1   110
## [2,] 107447440 2366 1800  565 1033  811    1   46    0     0    23
## [3,] 107447521 2933 2396  543  921 1566    0   11    0     0   115
```

Or, just the bits we want:

```
ctx$get("aAreas")[,1]
## [1] 107447478 107447440 107447521
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the numbers only you can try this:

```
(?:\\n\[)(\d+)
```

Comment: This won't _capture_ `\\n\[`, but it will _match_ it. For instance, this would not work `stringr::str_extract_all(x, '(?:\\n\\[)(\\d+)')`